# How to track updates for my employee fact table?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, temporal-tables

I have the following fact table which is composed by IDs :

```
Employee SK EmployeeId Manager EmployeeStatus EmployeeType PrimaryFunction From       To
10          249        3       2              3            34              27/10/2018 NULL
11          45         89      1              2            55              27/10/2018 NULL
```

If we have an update on the EmployeeStatus for the EmployeeId=249 and an update on the EmployeeType for the EmployeeId=45, my fact table should be like following :

```
Employee SK EmployeeId Manager EmployeeStatus EmployeeType PrimaryFunction From       To
10          249        3       2              3            34              27/10/2018 28/10
11          45         89      1              2            55              27/10/2018 29/10
12          249        3       1              3            34              28/10/2019 NULL
33          45         89      1              4            55              29/10/2019 NULL
```

Should I implement temporal tables in this case ?
If I want to add a column to capture where the update was made like for example we changed the EmployeeStatus of EmployeeId=249 , the column update will get Status, how should I proceed?
If I am using a temporal table how to use it as an OLE DB Source in SSIS to get the current and historical records?

Comment: Using a column to store "what changed" isn't needed, and would mean you would have to store Delimited data when more than one column is changed. You can infer what has changed because the value won't be the way. If you mean the User is leave "notes" then yes, you can store those, but that type of data is free text, so won't be useable from a query perspective. A temporal table would would be something like this yes, or otherwise a tradition SCD could be used. Personally, I haven't worked with Temporal Table, but I don't think you have to do anything different with the queries when using OLEDB

Comment: @Larnu can we apply SCD for many attributes at the same time?

Comment: As in, can the value of many rows be changed? Yes, you "void" the old row and insert the new.

Comment: @xXx, on sql 2k12 I use triggers to store old values in table <Basic table>History. On 2k16+ You can use temporal tables. History tables named by same manner - <BasicTable>History. In this case You don't have to write some triggers - changes stored by server itself. Fact table you can get by `union all` select from <BaseTable> and <BaseTable>history